# Flask Principal granular resource on demand

Tags: python, flask, flask-principal

I've been looking at this post:
http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/#granular-resource-protection

Now while there is nothing wrong with how it is currently working I can't see that it is very usable since at the time of login all posts are read and the `EditBlogPostNeed` is added  to the identity.

Imagine if I have been writing more than the normal number of posts it will long term not be a very good strategy as I would like to check the post as I access the view `/posts/<post_id>`.

Is there a way to do this check on each request for the view using `Flask Principal`?

I can of course get around it very easily with a lazy relationship query and filter but I want to use `Flask Principal`.

Comment: Nope and I stopped using flask because of this and some other issues not easily solvable in flask. I'm now using webob instead for full control.

Comment: Here is the related issue on Flask-Principal github: https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-principal/issues/6

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question entirely, but this might help. In a Flask app, I'm using Flask-Principal for role permission such as admin and editor, and I'm also using it for granular resource protection as described in the [Flask-Principal docs](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/). In my case I'm checking if a user has permission to access a particular account. In each view the identity is loaded and the permission is checked.

In the **view**:

```
@login_required
def call_list(id, page=1):

    dept = models.Department.query.get_or_404(id)
    view_permission = auth.ViewAccountPermission(dept.office.account_id)

    if view_permission.can():
        # do something
```

The **custom permission**:

```
ViewAccount = namedtuple('View', ['method', 'value'])
ViewAccountNeed = partial(ViewAccount, 'view')

class ViewAccountPermission(Permission):
    def __init__(self, account_id):
        need = ViewAccountNeed(unicode(account_id))
        super(ViewAccountPermission, self).__init__(need)
```

And in the **identity loader function**:

```
if hasattr(current_user, 'assigned_accounts'):
    for account_id in current_user.assigned_accounts():
        identity.provides.add(auth.ViewAccountNeed(unicode(account_id)))
```

Answer (score 1):

While Flask-Principal is the most popular plugin, it is unnecessary complicated and it just doesn't work in the most cases I need it. I have been trying to force it to work the way I like it, but I have never succeeded. Luckily, I have found an extremely straightforward and lightweight module - [permission](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/permission):

### Usage

First you need to define your own rules by subclassing `Rule` then
override `check()` and `deny()`:

```
# rules.py
from flask import session, flash, redirect, url_for
from permission import Rule

class UserRule(Rule):
    def check(self):
        """Check if there is a user signed in."""
        return 'user_id' in session

    def deny(self):
        """When no user signed in, redirect to signin page."""
        flash('Sign in first.')
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
```

Then you define permissions by subclassing `Permission` and override `rule()`:

```
# permissions.py
from permission import Permission
from .rules import UserRule

class UserPermission(Permission):
    """Only signin user has this permission."""
    def rule(self):
        return UserRule()
```

There are 4 ways to use the `UserPermission` defined above:

**1. Use as view decorator**

```
from .permissions import UserPermission

@app.route('/settings')
@UserPermission()
def settings():
    """User settings page, only accessable for sign-in user."""
    return render_template('settings.html')
```

**2. Use in view codes**

```
from .permissions import UserPermission

@app.route('/settions')
def settings():
    permission = UserPermission()
    if not permission.check()
        return permission.deny()
    return render_template('settings.html')
```

**3. Use in view codes (using `with` statement)**

```
from .permissions import UserPermission

@app.route('/settions')
def settings():
    with UserPermission():
        return render_template('settings.html')
```

**4. Use in Jinja2 templates**

First you need to inject your defined permissions to template context:

```
from . import permissions

@app.context_processor
def inject_vars():
    return dict(
        permissions=permissions
    )
```

then in templates:

```
{% if permissions.UserPermission().check() %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('new') }}">New</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything I can find on this topic seems overly obtuse. While not what I initially desired, I've decided to simply handle this manually in my view functions. It's more explicit, and it reduces extra queries against the database. Do note that I'm still using `flask-security` for its out-of-the-box role-based authentication (which is still implemented via `flask-principal` via its `@roles_accepted('role')` decorator.

```
@app.route('/my_accounts/', methods = ['GET'])
@app.route('/my_accounts/<int:id>/', methods = ['GET'])
@roles_accepted('client')
def my_accounts(id=None):

    if id:
        account = Account.query.get_or_404(id)

        if account.owner == current_user:
            return render_template("my_account.html",
                                   title = "Account: {0}".format(account.name),
                                   account = account)
        else:
            abort(403)

    accounts = Account.query.filter_by(owner=current_user).all()

    return render_template("my_accounts.html",
                           title = 'My Accounts',
                           accounts = accounts)
```

Comment: u touched my heart

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the assumption that you already know how flask principal works, and how it's integrated with database.

**First, We only need to store Needs in the database,
if you don't know why, I don't recommend you to read my answer below**

Then, back to your question,We need to edit an article,how to grannel control it?

```
@app.route('/article/edit/<id>'):
@Permission(Need('edit', 'article')).require()
def article(id):
    pass
```

User's identity

```
id = identity(user.id)
id.provide.add(Need('edit','article'))
```

Then the user have the permission to edit the article.`@Permission(Need('edit', 'article')).require()` will return true for every article even though the user is not the author of the article,This is your problem ,right??

*Below is how I solve this problem*

because the default Permission.require() doesn't provide any args to pass into , So I define my own the Permisson and IdentityContext and pass in the article id and the article Model, then I check the article's user_id with flask login's current_user.id

```
class MyPermission(Permission):
    pass


class MyIdentityContext():

    pass
```

If the user is the article's author then I return True, the User can edit the article, If not, return False, then it works.

--------I will update more detail later------------